# I am getting the error 'expected a quoted string', when I use certain rss feed. XMLParser

Tags: java, android, rss

I am getting the above error message when I use the second feed in the array, the other feeds work fine; it is just that particular feed which is throwing the error.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

(The feed array is in the rssRun() method, and it is the second feed which is causing me error)

UPDATE:

It seems that the problem was, is that sometimes 'doc' proved to be null, therefore throwing an error. So I just put a try catch method around the code, and this seems to have done the trick....any item which throws an error will just be skipped.

MainCode:

```
package com.androidhive.xmlparsing;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    //static final String URL = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
    String[] URL = new String[3];
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        rssRun();

    }



    public void rssRun()
    {
        URL[0] = "http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportonline_uk_edition/football/teams/a/arsenal/rss.xml";
        URL[1] = "http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,11661,00.xml";
        URL[2] = "http://www.football365.com/premier-league/rss";

        //URL[3] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
        for (int f= 0;f < 3;f++)
        {
            count+=1;


        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL[f]); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        //Log.e("XML", xml);

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        //Log.e("NODELIST", nl.toString());
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            //map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getCharacterDataFromElement(e, KEY_DESC));
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));            
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
            map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }


        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST, KEY_LINK }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost, R.id.link});
        //if (count==3)
        //{
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        //}

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }
    }


    public String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e, String str) {
        NodeList n = e.getElementsByTagName(str);   
        Element e1=(Element) n.item(0);

        Node child = e1.getFirstChild();
        if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
          CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
          return cd.getData();
        }
        return "";
        }


}
```

XMlParser:

```
package com.androidhive.xmlparsing;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            dbf.setCoalescing(true);   
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
    public final String getElementValue2( Node elem ) {  
        Node child;  
        if( elem != null){  
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()){  
                for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){  
                    //if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){  
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE || child.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE  ){       
                        return child.getNodeValue();  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        return "";  
        //return elem.getTextContent();  
    } 

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue2(n.item(0));
        }


}
```

Error Log:

```
08-27 11:32:42.327: E/Error:(5730): Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:50 in java.io.StringReader@42c223e8) 
08-27 11:32:42.337: D/AndroidRuntime(5730): Shutting down VM
08-27 11:32:42.337: W/dalvikvm(5730): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41966da0)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730): Process: com.androidhive.xmlparsing, PID: 5730
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.xmlparsing/com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity.rssRun(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java:71)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java:48)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
08-27 11:32:42.347: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
```

Comment: What is line 71 in `AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java`?

Comment: This line is on 71:  NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

Comment: do check if doc is null or not

Comment: Hmmm, thanks but it still brings back the same error.

Comment: doc is null. you need to fix it. you are calling getElementsByTagName on null

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I seem to have fixed it with a try{} catch() method; as if it finds that the doc is null, it will skip it and not throw an error....this seems to be doing the trick for now. Thanks for the help!